# Grid not resizing to MinWidth supplied via ArrangeOverride

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have 2 grids enclosed in a custom Grid panel as follows:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

    <!-- Width and Height of this grid are bound to ScrollViewer's ViewportWidth/Height -->
    <CustomGrid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="300"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="ProblematicGrid" Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="500">
            <!-- This grid has 5 star-sized columns with MinWidths that sum up to 500 -->
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="OtherGrid" Grid.Column="1" />
    </CustomGrid>

</ScrollViewer>
```

`CustomGrid` is just a custom panel I wrote for diagnostic purposes. It inherits `Grid` and overrides `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`. In `ArrangeOverride` it passes hard-coded values of 500 and 300 to **ProblematicGrid** and **OtherGrid** respectively.

The behavior I'm seeing is:

- When I run the application containing this `UserControl` with an initial window size smaller than 800, **ProblematicGrid** and **OtherGrid** render with their respective `MinWidth`s.
- If I expand the application then shrink it back again, **ProblematicGrid**'s `ActualWidth` never goes back to its `MinWidth` of 500 even though it is passed to it directly in `ArrangeOverride` of `CustomPanel`.

My question is why is this happening? What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Is your overridden ArrangeOverride method ever called when you shrink the main window (i.e. did you place a breakpoint to verify it's hit)? Due to the ScrollViewer I wouldn't expect CustomGrid to get smaller at any time at all.

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, I don't think you really need to pass in any hard-coded values for the size. It should be pretty simple to just bind all the widths you need easily. Is there any particular thing you absolutely must have from overriding Measure and Arrange?

Comment: @Clemens Yes, it is. I did verify this with a debugger.

Comment: @Meloviz Well, you're right but even though CustomGrid's Width and Height are bound to the ViewportWidth/ViewportHeight of the ScrollViewer, ProblematicGrid does not shrink to its MinSize. This is why I took it one step further and wrote CustomGrid to investigate the issue and make sure MinWidth was being passed to ProblematicGrid. But ProbelmaticGrid won't shrink to its MinWidth still.

Comment: Then I think your issue might be that some code in your override is setting at least one explicit width somewhere. Without seeing the code pertaining to the issue, I think that's about the best I can come up with.